# How can I get water to drain out of a sink where the drain opening is higher than the bowl bottom?

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

First off I screwed up where I drilled the hole for the drain. The middle of the bowl is actually raised so the water pools in a circle around the drain:

[image]

[image]

I'm curious what my options are now... Is there any way I can salvage this? There's about 3-4mm of standing water in a ring around the bowl.

Could I put another smaller drain in back of the bowl? I'm wondering if I could even plug the hole I drilled and not have it look awful.

Comment: This is more an arts-and-crafts question than one about home improvement, but the only thing that comes to mind is to fill the bottom of the bowl with transparent epoxy (like you'd use on furniture to seal in bottle caps, for example), which would leave you at least with a level surface. I'm not sure how durable it would be in a wet situation, though.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, @isherwood is right: "arts-and-crafts" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try posting it there. Also thank you @isherwood I think the epoxy idea is a great one.

Comment: what's the bowl made out of? what is the surface finish?

Comment: The bowl appears to be ceramic. The surface finish seems to be some sort of glaze with an eggshell finish with a slight crackle

Comment: Wait. *You* drilled that hole? BS. How?!?! lol - Oh, before it was fired, *you made the hole*. Now you want to drill a hole in previously fired ceramic. Wouldn't you have to reglaze it?

Comment: It either slumped in the kiln or it was messed up even before making the hole, or you messed (slumped) it up making the hole. I think your only salvage at this point was the learning curve. Now it's a fruit bowl.

Comment: @Mazura if it's ceramic a diamond hole grinder would be the ideal tool,  but even a carbide burr will work if you're patient.

Comment: A real conundrum, May not be the best vessel for a sink.

Answer (score 0):

Arts and crafts , NO it was a messed up drain   The only option is to have the drain line and trap below the bottom of the sink.

Comment: I get the impression that you didn't read the question carefully, Ed. :)

Comment: I have read it several times but it did not make sense or was a factory second. I have not run into that big of offset in a sink bottom.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your answer, which seems to discuss the pipes. Since the bowl has a thickness, the pipes already _are_ below the bowl.

Answer (score -2):

Fill the bowl with clear epoxy until it's level with the drain hole. You can then be satisfied with a flat bottomed bowl that won't drain completely, but will leave a thin film of water to evaporate instead of a puddle.

Or, continue on...

Next, use a thick, quick setting epoxy to make a slight slope from the edge of the bowl to the drain in the middle. This will establish the proper slope on the bottom of the bowl to ensure correct drainage.

---

No. I do not know if epoxy exists in a clear enough form to do the job without obscuring the decoration on the bottom of the bowl to the satisfaction of the OP. Just tossing out an idea a year later.